# Ruby on Rails: Javascript: prototype.js:3483 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Why does this error happen? I didn't do anything to that file?
my links that call javascript are within a from... that shouldn't be a problem though.. right?

The offending code block:

```
  getElements: function(form) {
     return $A($(form).getElementsByTagName('*')).inject([],
          function(elements, child) {
            if (Form.Element.Serializers[child.tagName.toLowerCase()])
              elements.push(Element.extend(child));
            return elements;
          }
        );  
  },
```

the second line here is line 3484

Comment: Can you provide the code for the view that causes this error?

Comment: sure thing, I'm pretty sure prototype.js hasn't been modified at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is directly correlated with

[Ruby on Rails: nested forms. One for bulk actions, the inner for Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230792/ruby-on-rails-nested-forms-one-for-bulk-actions-the-inner-for-searching)